# Cannot compile a signed APK in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating to AS 3.3, there seems to be a bug in the "Generate Signed Bundle/APK" dialog.
After choosing Bundle or APK format, moving to the next page and setting the module/keystore pass, I can't move by pressing next because I get this popup:

```
Please specify a destination folder for the signed apk
```

There is no editbox to specify a destination folder.
Anyone else experienced this? I want to know if it's because of the material theme plugin hiding an extra editbox. Otherwise I'll file a bug.

Comment: Sometimes in my Mac, some popups appear hidden under the main window or minimised (occuppying a really small portion of the window) so I have to guess where they have appeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE** The latest Android Studio (currently 3.3.1) has fixed the bug.

**For Android Studio version < 3.3.1**

This seemed to be a bug in AS after upgrading to 3.3. The bug is caused by the hidden checkbox which SHOULDN'T have been evaluated when pressing next if it's invisible (and somehow missed by the Android engineers).

Here's what worked for me:

1. Regardless if you want APK or bundle, choose Bundle
2. Even if not required, check the option "Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps"
3. Choose any file
4. Press Next (it will work)
5. Press back twice, choose if APK/Bundle, then in next page, no need for the checkbox "Export (…)" if not required
6. Build & upvote this answer if it worked to help others

Comment: @FilipeOS as mentioned, this method will work on both! but you just have to go thru Bundle first, follow the steps, then press back and choose APK, it will work

Comment: In my case, no encrypted key is generated. Android Studio 3.5.3

Comment: for me it just stuck over here...nothing changed at all..

Answer (score 0):

I had in my build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

and changed it to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

After that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've to revert back the gradle dependency to 4.2.0 from 4.2.1

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

What @RJFares said is correct, but in my case, in addition to that I needed to revert version of gradle dependency from 3.3.0 to 3.2.1 in **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
....
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
...
}
}
```

To have a complete answer in one I'm copying @RJFares's answer

1. Regardless if you want APK or bundle, choose Bundle
2. Even if not required, check the option "Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps"
3. Choose any file
4. Press Next (it will work)
5. Press back twice, choose if APK/Bundle, then in next page, no need for the checkbox "Export (…)" if not required

Comment: this isn't required. I myself am running gradle 3.3.0. 
I suggest you go back to 3.3.0 and try again. Keep in mind the problem is with the dialog itself and not any dependency you have!