# Error while generate signed apk: please specify destination folder for the signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio

[Error after update today to Android Studio 3.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luuEQ.png)

Comment: my college also experiencing this after update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot compile a signed APK in Android Studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196270/cannot-compile-a-signed-apk-in-android-studio-3-3)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got the solution from other thread - [Cannot compile a signed APK in Android Studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196270/cannot-compile-a-signed-apk-in-android-studio-3-3)

Here's what worked for me:

1.Regardless if you want APK or bundle, choose Bundle

2.Even if not required, check the option "Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps"

3.Choose any file

4.Press Next (it will work)

5.Press back twice, choose if APK/Bundle, then in next page, no need for the checkbox "Export (…)" if not required

6.Build & upvote this answer if it worked to help others

Comment: Sorry, it appears to be working (starts compilation) but at the end, I've received this other problem

`Cause: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1:

jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

and obviously I'm using right password.

Comment: This happened to me in the latest version of IntelliJ with Android Gradle 3.5.0-rc03. What an odd bug.

Answer (score 1):

What @Georgi said is correct, but in my case, in addition to that I needed to revert version of gradle dependency from 3.3.0 to 3.2.1 in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
....
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
...
}
}
```

To have a complete answer in one I'm copying @Georgi's answer

1. Regardless if you want APK or bundle, choose Bundle
2. Even if not required, check the option "Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps"
3. Choose any file
4. Press Next (it will work)
5. Press back twice, choose if APK/Bundle, then in next page, no need for the checkbox "Export (…)" if not required