# Unable to generate a signed APK for release in Android Studio

Tags: android, passwords, apk, release, keystore

I'm trying to generate a signed APK for my app in Android Studio by going into Build->Generate Signed Bundle/APK , but I keep getting this error when I select the release build variant.

> Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>     Failed to read key keystore from store "C:\Users[PATH]\keystore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

I'm pretty sure that my password is correct because the apk generates correctly when I select the debug build variant instead of release. The keystore also works fine for my other projects.

I tried cleaning, rebuilding the project,invalidating the cache/restarting, and changing the destination folder, but nothing worked. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `keystore` file for first, in you example you creating file with name `keystore.jks` If its correct and really present in folder user check alias

Comment: The keystore and alias are correct. I'm able to generate a debug apk using them, but not release for some reason.

Comment: The debug build will (or should) use an entirely different keystore when building than one that is built for release so, you can't go by that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was my build.gradle version.
Same solution as @S. Gissel in [Cannot compile a signed APK in Android Studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196270/cannot-compile-a-signed-apk-in-android-studio-3-3)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by providing the specific file path of my .jks and not just the folder.

ex.

***INCORRECT*** key store path

```
C:\Users\john\Desktop\Projects\ProjectName
```

***CORRECT*** key store path

```
C:\Users\john\Desktop\Projects\ProjectName\helloworld.jks
```